# react firebase config .env file doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have a question about configuration of firebase with a react app. I put all firebase config info in .env file at the top directory as environmental variables. When I tried to use them as `process.env.REACT_APP_smth`, they all didn't work. Once I replaced the variables to real, raw config info, my app worked. But For sure, it's too dangerous so I don't wanna do it.

Also, the .env file was darker in vs code like mentioning it's not valid or smth.
[image]

Anyone knows how to tackle with this issue??
Thanks for your time and effort here in advance.

### .env

I replaced REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY with 123456789.

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY = "123456789"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN = "kinnikuhub.firebaseapp.com"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL = "https://kinnikuHub.firebaseio.com"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID = "kinnikuhub"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET = "kinnikuhub.appspot.com"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID = "131675559"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID = "1:131675559:web:3ca3bbad263b6be90ff282"
```

### firebase.js

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { addDoc, getDocs, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { collection } from "firebase/firestore";
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export const db = getFirestore();

export const auth = getAuth(app);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      
      // todo: Why create users table?? To let users have personal info, number of answers and quizzes cretaed, biography, sns links, etc
      // todo: 1st, check if res.user exists
      const userCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users');
      let userExistance = false;
      console.log(`currentUser.uid => ${res.user.uid}`)
      console.log(userExistance)
      const checkUserExists = async () => {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(userCollectionRef);
        querySnapshot.forEach( (doc) => {
          // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
          // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());      
          // console.log(`currentUser.uid => ${res.user.uid}`)
          if (doc.data().uid === res.user.uid) {
            userExistance = true;
            // console.log(userExistance)
            return 0;
          }
        });
        console.log(userExistance)
        // todo: 2nd, add this user to users collection if it doesn't exists
        if (userExistance === false) {
          console.log(`userExistance is false, meaning this user hasn't been registerd so I am going add the user into users collection!!! ${res.user.displayName}, ${JSON.stringify(res.user)}`)
          const addUser = async () => {
            const payload = {
              username: res.user.displayName,
              uid: res.user.uid,
              email: res.user.email,
              photoURL: res.user.photoURL,
              createdAt: new Date(),
              bio: "biography",
            };
            await addDoc(userCollectionRef, payload);
          }
          addUser();
        } else {
          console.log('This user has been already registered!! So glad he/she keeps using this app!!')
        }
      }
      checkUserExists();


    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
}

// export const AuthState = () => {
//   const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({})
//   onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
//     if (user) {
//       const username = user.displayName;
//       const uid = user.uid;
//       const email = user.email;
//       const photoURL = user.photoURL
//       // const emailVerified = user.emailVerified
  
//       setUserInfo({username, uid, email, photoURL});
      
//       console.log(`username => ${username}`)
//       console.log(`uid => ${uid}`)
//       console.log(`email => ${email}`)
//       console.log(`photoURL => ${photoURL}`)
//       // console.log(`emailVerified => ${emailVerified}`)
//       return userInfo;
//     } else {
//       console.log("no user signed in")
//     }
//   })
// }

// sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
//   .then(() => {
//     console.log('email verification sent!')
//   })
```

##.gitignore

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local
.env
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

Background:
Yesterday, I initialized my pc to install Monterey in my macbook air and files in the pc were all gone. Then, I git-cloned the repo of this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have forgotten to restart the whole app. run `npm start` again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You have everything correct from what I see except the file naming itself. I too struggled to try to get this to work until I made this simple change:

Try renaming your 'firebase.js' file to 'firebase.config.js', this will read your process.env variables as actual variables.

Answer (score 0):

The variable values in .env should not be enclosed in the quotation marks. Remove the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, let me share, how I am able to solve the problem.

firstly, change the file name which should be `firebase.config.js` and `.env.local`

secondly, set those files in the proper position. Here,  files should be settled in the same as where package.json file is allocated.

Now, in the `.env.local` file, the variable name must be started like this,

EX:

```
VITE_apiKey = abc
VITE_authDomain = abc
VITE_projectId = abc
VITE_storageBucket = abc
VITE_messagingSenderId = abc
VITE_appId = abc
[replace abc with firebase API keys]
```

Lastly, in `firebase.config.js` file, variable should be imported like this,

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_apiKey,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_authDomain,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_projectId,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_messagingSenderId,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_appId
};
```

This way I am able to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Faced similar issue and what solved it for me was putting the process.env.something in template literals (aka template strings) like below.

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: `${process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY}`,
  authDomain: `${process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN}`,
  projectId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}`,
  storageBucket: `${process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET}`,
  messagingSenderId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID}`,
  appId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID}`,
};
```

Answer (score -3):

I also had the same issue. I solved the issue by only replacing the projectID with the actual variable.

ex:-

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
    projectId: "personal-portfolio-f1e9f",
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
    appId: process.env.APPID,
    measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENTID
  };
```